# launch x11vnc on bootup

Tags: arch-linux, x11, systemd, x11vnc

I am using archlinux version 3.10.27-1-ARCH on my remote PC and I would like it to launch x11vnc server on successful bootup. Though i can start the x11vnc server manually, I am having trouble starting it up automatically. The configuration of `/etc/systemd/system/x11vnc.service` is as follows

---

```
[Unit]
Description=VNC Server for X11
Requires=graphical.target
After=graphical.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -display :0 -nopw
```

---

The status of the service using command:`systemctl status x11vnc`

```
x11vnc.service - VNC Server for X11
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/x11vnc.service; enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

---

And the dBus output of command: `dmesg|grep x11vnc`

```
[    5.467201] systemd[1]: Found dependency on x11vnc.service/start
[    5.467285] systemd[1]: Breaking ordering cycle by deleting job x11vnc.service/start
[    5.467335] systemd[1]: Job x11vnc.service/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with graphical.target/start
```

---

I do feel from the `dmesg` output there is a cyclic dependency, but I am not able to understand what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this thread which shows a similar task of setting up `x11vnc` as a Systemd service. The thread is titled: [Index» Newbie Corner» how to enable x11vnc at startup using systemd ?](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=168756).

*From a comment in that thread*

1. Create the file: `/etc/systemd/system/x11vnc.service`

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=VNC Server for X11
   Requires=display-manager.service
   After=display-manager.service

   [Service]
   Type=forking
   ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -norc -forever -shared -bg -rfbauth /etc/x11vnc.pass -allow 192.168.1. -autoport 5900 -o /var/log/x11vnc.log
   ```
2. Create the file: `/etc/systemd/system/graphical.target`

   ```
   #  This file is part of systemd.
   #
   #  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
   #  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
   #  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
   #  (at your option) any later version.

   [Unit]
   Description=Graphical Interface
   Documentation=man:systemd.special(7)
   Requires=multi-user.target
   After=multi-user.target
   Conflicts=rescue.target
   Wants=display-manager.service
   Wants=x11vnc.service
   AllowIsolate=yes

   [Install]
   Alias=default.target
   ```
3. Enable Systemd service

   ```
   $ sudo systemctl enable graphical.target
   ```

   This should create a link like this:

   > /etc/systemd/system/default.target -> /etc/systemd/system/graphical.target
4. Reboot

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Though I did see the link earlier during my google searches, I did not try it for some reason. I edited my `x11vnc.service` with yours as starting point, and now the x11vnc server starts up automatically on bootup

Comment: @zeena - That wonderful news, glad this resolved your issue, thanks for the Q!

Answer (score 0):

Just for closure, the `x11vnc.service` that made it happen for me is as follows

```
[Unit]
Description=VNC Server for X11  
Requires=display-manager.service
After=display-manager.service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -norc -forever -shared -bg -rfbauth /etc/x11vnc.pass -autoport 5900 -o /var/log/x11vnc.log -auth /var/run/slim.auth
```

the `graphical.target` and steps are identical to answer given by `slm` above.